# InputStream / RestTemplate taking forever to copy file

Tags: java, android, spring

I have this block of code that copies a file to a remote server using an `InputStream`:

```
    final InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(CACHED_CLONE_FILE_NAME));
    final RequestCallback requestCallback = new RequestCallback()
    {
        public void doWithRequest(final ClientHttpRequest request)
        {
            try {
                request.getHeaders().add("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");

                OutputStream procOutput =  request.getBody();
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(procOutput);
                IOUtils.copy(fis, bos); 
            }
            catch (IOException ex) { 
            }
        }
    };

    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());

    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setBufferRequestBody(false);
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
    final HttpMessageConverterExtractor<String> responseExtractor = new HttpMessageConverterExtractor<String>(String.class, restTemplate.getMessageConverters());
    restTemplate.execute(urlToPost, HttpMethod.POST, requestCallback, responseExtractor);
```

It works, except that for a small file (4MB) it takes hours to copy it over. Why is this occurring, and what can I do about the performance?

This code is being used on an Android device, and there are no network problems.

Comment: Why are you using RestTemplate?  Using Spring in an Android app is VERY unusual, I'm not surprised it has issues.  Spring on Android is basically never done.

Comment: I'm not sure, I wasn't the one who wrote the code. I'm thinking of getting rid of it.

Comment: If you want a good answer to this, I suggest you add the Spring tag.  While there are devs out there who may know Spring and Android, its a minority.  If there's something wrong with this code a Spring guru will be the one to find it, this is using 0 Android functionality.